# TabPageIndicator looks different in different Android versions

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-styles, viewpagerindicator, tabpage

Hi I am using [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) library.

My project's Target Build is 5.0.1.

In Lollipop version its looking good as expected as below.

[image]

But in Jelly Bean version 4.2.1(Samsung Galaxy) its looking as follows.

[image]

**The styles.xml :**

```
<!-- TO CHECK WITH LIBRARY ADDED STYLES FROM THE LISTSAMPLES PROJECT -->
<style name="StyledIndicators" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomCirclePageIndicator</item>
    <item name="vpiLinePageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomLinePageIndicator</item>
    <item name="vpiTitlePageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomTitlePageIndicator</item>
    <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomTabPageIndicator</item>
    <item name="vpiUnderlinePageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomUnderlinePageIndicator</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTitlePageIndicator">
    <item name="android:background">#18FF0000</item>
    <item name="footerColor">#FFAA2222</item>
    <item name="footerLineHeight">1dp</item>
    <item name="footerIndicatorHeight">3dp</item>
    <item name="footerIndicatorStyle">underline</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#AA000000</item>
    <item name="selectedColor">#FF000000</item>
    <item name="selectedBold">true</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomLinePageIndicator">
    <item name="strokeWidth">4dp</item>
    <item name="lineWidth">30dp</item>
    <item name="unselectedColor">#FF888888</item>
    <item name="selectedColor">#FF880000</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomCirclePageIndicator">
    <item name="fillColor">#FF888888</item>
    <item name="strokeColor">#FF000000</item>
    <item name="strokeWidth">2dp</item>
    <item name="radius">10dp</item>
    <item name="centered">true</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTabPageIndicator" parent="Widget.TabPageIndicator">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_tab_indicator</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomTabPageIndicator.Text</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:showDividers">middle</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:fadingEdge">horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:fadingEdgeLength">8dp</item>

</style>

<style name="CustomTabPageIndicator.Text" parent="android:TextAppearance.Large">
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomUnderlinePageIndicator">
    <item name="selectedColor">#FFCC0000</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FFCCCCCC</item>
    <item name="fadeLength">1000</item>
    <item name="fadeDelay">1000</item>
</style>
<!-- UPTO THIS LINE -->
```

1. What mistake I did?
2. Is anything going wrong with styles.xml ?

If need more detail,please ask me , I am open to provide.